# NavigationStack with route switching. How to bring "value:" from the NavigationLink since already filled by the Route.link?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm using the new `NavigationStack` from **SwiftUI**. I'm using it with enum route switching.

How can I bring a "value:" to the "destination" view from the NavigationLink just like I would for a regular `NavigationLink` without the enum Route switch?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

enum RouteNew {
    case linkOne, linkTwo
}

struct Nav: View {
    @State private var pathNew = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $pathNew) { // Stack with Path binding
            
            NavigationLink("Link One", value: RouteNew.linkOne) // How to give the value here that I want to bring into the destinatio  view?
            NavigationLink("Link Two", value: RouteNew.linkTwo) // How to give the value here that I want to bring into the destinatio  view?
            
            .navigationDestination(for: RouteNew.self) { route in
                switch route { // switch
                    case.linkOne:
                        viewOne(path: $pathNew)
                    case.linkTwo:
                        viewTwo(path: $pathNew)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct viewOne: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var valueToImport: String  // How to bring this value in from the Navigation link?
    var body: some View {
        Text("View One value: \(valueToImport)")
    }
}

struct viewTwo: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var valueToImport: String // How to bring this value in from the Navigation link?
    var body: some View {
        Text("View Two value: \(valueToImport)")
    }
}

struct viewThree: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var valueToImport: String // How to bring this value in from the Navigation link?
    var body: some View {
        Text("View Three value: \(valueToImport)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the global routing you can pass the value to view using case let.

eg:

```
enum Route: Hashable {
    case list
    case create(Animal)
    case detail(Animal)
}
```

then in your routing pass it like this:

```
@main
struct LearnNavApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                        switch route {
                            case .list:
                                Text("Show all animals")
                            case .create(let animal):
                                Text("Create an animal \(animal.name)")
                            case .detail(let animal):
                                Text("Detail \(animal.name)")
                        }
                    }
            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
NavigationLink("Go to Detail", value: Route.detail(Animal(name: "Rabbit")))
```

Your can read this [original article](https://azamsharp.com/2022/07/02/global-routing-using-navigation-stack.html) for more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "routing" and use destination values as designed:

```
.navigationDestination(for: Link1.self) { link1 in
    ...
}
.navigationDestination(for: Link2.self) { link2 in
    ...
}
```